# Is it possible to apply for a PR/passport if someone doesn't stay in the country?

Tags: residency, passport, portugal

I am talking about Portugal.

As far as I know, Portugal requires a person to stay in the country for 5 years to be eligible for applying for a Portuguese passport.

Suppose, someone gets a Portuguese visa and starts to live in Portugal. Then after 1 year due time, he gets a TRC (Temporary Residence Card) and moves to some other country in **Schengen** (say, Germany) and continues to stay there.

Does this affect his application for a Portuguese PR (Permanent Residency)?

Suppose, he moves out of Portugal to stay in another **Schengen** country after getting a PR.

Does this affect his application for a Portuguese passport later on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question emphasized that this person would go to a Schengen country but it's important to understand that the Schengen rules legally have no bearing on this whatsoever. While the EU has made it easier to move around and possibly cheat a little, rules around citizenship are still strictly national matters as are, for the most part, rules on long-term stay and residence. To the extent that there is a requirement to reside in Portugal before applying for citizenship (and no special permission or exemption), the rule would therefore apply equally to stays in Schengen and/or EU countries as it does to third countries.

Furthermore, I don't know precisely about Portugal but in several other European countries the residence requirement for naturalization is a material requirement. That means that you need to have made country your home and be physically present most of the time, not merely hold a right to reside or a specific document. In that context whether you are allowed to keep the permit or managed to do it illegally is not directly relevant. The legal definition of a “resident” can even differ for different areas of the law (say taxes vs. citizenship).

Answer (score 1):

> As far as I know, Portugal requires a person to stay in the country for 5 years to be eligible for applying for a Portuguese passport.

I assume you mean: obtaining **citizenship**, which is a pre-requierment for a Portuguese passport.

> Then after 1 year due time, he gets a TRC (Temporary Residence Card) and moves to some other country in Schengen (say, Germany) and continues to stay there.
>   Does this affect his application for a Portuguese PR (Permanent Residency)?

A residence permit issued by one country only allows you to **reside** in that country

- it will allow you to **visit** the other Schengen countries, but not to reside

If you move to Germany, you must apply for a residence permit there.

> Suppose, he moves out of Portugal to stay in another Schengen country after getting a PR.
>   Does this affect his application for a Portuguese passport [citizenship] later on?

The time you reside **outside** of Portugal will *probably* not count as residing inside Portugal since, depending on the jurisdiction, a residence permit becomes invalid when you move to another country.

This would then effect the eligibility for Portuguese citizenship.

Comment: is this rule same for Germany also?

Comment: @user366312 For Germany it is **definitely** the case, for Portugal I assume it also. Also a residence permit becomes invalid after a stay of longer than 6 months outside the country unless an exception is applied for (to take care of someone in your home country or professional reasons) beforhand.

Comment: *unless an exception is applied for (to take care of someone in your home country or professional reasons) beforhand* --- how about education?

Comment: @user366312 In Germany, that would be left to the discretion of the immigration office to decide. The law itself only states that exceptions can be applied for. How this is dealt with elsewhere I cannot say.

Comment: "since, depending on the jurisdiction, a residence permit becomes invalid when you move to another country": I am also unfamiliar with the laws of Portugal, but in the countries I am familiar with, time residing outside the country may not count towards naturalization *even if* the residence permit remains valid during that time.

Comment: [§51(1)(7) AufthG](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_aufenthg/englisch_aufenthg.html#p0927) allow the foreigners authority to set a longer period than 6 months. § 51(3) also allows this for fulfillment of **compulsory military service**